# Android Record audio to file controller when calling WebRTC

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, recording

currently I'm developing Android app which using WebRTC native. I want to know if there is a way to record only my voice to file during the call? There is RecordedAudioToFileController.java but it will record my voice and caller voice also. I need to record my voice during the call only. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, we need to change the audio source in WebRTCAudioRecord from Voice communication to Mic.